# shell_exec func (PHP) returns wired output when trying to run python script

Tags: python, php

PHP Script

```
<?php
$data = "Variable from PHP Script";
$a = str_replace(' ','***',$data);
$output=shell_exec("python C:/xampp/htdocs/try.py "  .$a);
echo $output;
?>
```

Python Script

```
import sys
result = sys.argv[1]
print(result+" by python!")
```

In $a (in PHP),

when I use %&% (also any of these(%,|,&)) it generates

```
Variable% by python!
```

when I use *** it generates

```
Variable***from***PHP***Script by python!
```

What going on here and How can I solve it

Comment: you are not escaping you commandline arguments.

Comment: `$data = "\"Variable from PHP Script\"";` should escape the argument.